# In a MATLAB plot, how do I query the y-axis limits using the get command?

Tags: matlab, plot, get, propertyeditor

I do not understand how to use the get command to "query the y-axis limits." I know I can find the property related to the axis limits in the Property Editor, but I cannot find it and I got stuck.

Comment: `get(gca,'YLim')` or you can replace `gca` with the handles to any axes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a generalized version of my comment, you can fetch any property you want with the `get` command using the exact same name those properties have in the Property Editor/Inspector.

For instance, in your case the property `YLim` exists in the Property Inspector under this very name, so in a script/function you can fetch it using:

```
get(HandlestoAxis,'YLim')
```

where the output is a 1x2 vector and `HandlestoAxis` is the handles to any axis you want. For the current axis you can use `gca`.